# How to make hyper-v automatically resume replication?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

Lots of times I find that I have to click "Resume Replication" on my Virtual Machines.  Supposedly, this is a "by design" thing after a reboot.  Well, I have hosts staying up for weeks and then somewhere along the way I find that I have to do this.  Nothing was rebooted.

It's annoying and a little scary and quite frankly, it has made me lose confidence in Hyper-V.

Is there a way to have Windows automatically "Resume Replication" without me needing to remember to login and do it myself?

Is there a Schedule Task I can run? Powershell script?  CLI command?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Resume-VMReplication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/resume-vmreplication?view=winserver2012-ps) cmdlet?

You can use `Get-VMReplication` to find the current replication state and then run `Resume-VMReplication` if needed. Of course you can then schedule such a script.